# Repetitions on the same combination of factors in mixed ANOVA and its power analysis

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures, statistical-power, gpower

I am trying to decide the appropriate model and perform power analysis. Suppose a data contains 2 groups (A,B) and 28 participants from each group. All of those participants are measured 15 times on each of 8 conditions (c1,c2,...c8), so each participant get 8*15=120 continuous measurements in total. I understand the sample size should depends on the power analysis results so I am just giving example numbers referring to related studies in the same field.

The major question to be answered by the model is whether there is significant difference difference of c1 and c2 for group B, and difference of A and B in c1 (and some other similar comparisons). So the major goal is to test particular simple main effect or maybe called planned contrast.

My question is related to [How to deal with repeated measurements in the same condition of a factorial experiment?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46321/how-to-deal-with-repeated-measurements-in-the-same-condition-of-a-factorial-expe) but more about power analysis. I believe I can use either mixed ANOVA (groups as fixed between effect, conditions as fixed within effect, and participants as random effect) or mixed modeling. However, I don't usually observe *repetitions* (each participant has 15 measurements on each condition here) in a repeated measures ANOVA or mixed ANOVA. Therefore my concerns are as below.

1. If I could do mixed ANOVA, I plan to use `Superpower` package for power analysis. But the 'n' in `ANOVA_design` seems only refer to number of participants and there seems no way to consider number of repetitions. How to specify repetition number in `Superpower`?
   Similarly, G*Power software only allows input of 'Number of groups' (between factor) and 'Number of measurements' (within factor). Does this mean that the *repetition* doesn't affect the power? But my understanding is that it would at least affects the df of denominator and so the power.
2. For either mixed model or mixed ANOVA, should the power analysis be done on the planned contrast at all?
3. If yes to question 2, for a mixed effect model is built, how can `simr` beused for the power calculation for the planned contrast and simple main effect?

Thanks in advance and your help is really appreciated.